# Centring a PDF in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

Here is what my PDF looks like now when loaded in a `UIWebView`: (I put in a blue gradient as the `UIWebView`'s background so you can see what I mean better).

[image: Hi StackOverflow!]

I would like to centre that so that the bottom margin is the same as the top margin. How would I do this with a PDF (not local)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_MSEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CGFloat topInset = floor(([[self webView] frame].size.height - [[[self webView] scrollView] contentSize].height) / 2);
        [[[self webView] scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0)];
        [[[self webView] scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -topInset) animated:NO];
    });
}
```

This uses `UIWebView`'s internal `UIScrollView`. The content size is fetched from the scroll view and is taken from the overall web view. This gives the 'extra' space. Half this and use it as a top inset and you have it centred. You do need to initially scroll the view to the correct place yourself using `setContentOffset:` as this seems to be set internally before we manage to set the inset. From then on everything should work.

The `dispatch_after` is unfortunately a requirement in iOS 8. The `contentSize` will be 0 if you fetch it too early after `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with iOS, but there's a variety of ways to vertically center content in HTML.

One is to [wrap your content in a table](http://jsfiddle.net/rTRsV/).

```
<style>
  html, body, table {
    height: 100%;
  }
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <object .../>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another is to [apply table-like styles to elements that are already wrapping your content](http://jsfiddle.net/EEJg3/).

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
<center>
  <object .../>
</center>
```

A solution with no markup is to [use CSS flexible boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/qDdQz/).

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
  }
</style>
<object .../>
```

Comment: Try loading the PDF as an `<object>` within some HTML wrapper content, possibly with `[UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseUrl:]`.